# Filling voids in ASTER stereo-images for DEM generation using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, aster

I'm trying to use a stereo-pair of ASTER images to generate a DEM (in ERDAS Imagine). However, the mountains are rather cloudy and the images can't be used as they are. But the relevant parts (valley bottoms) are well visible.

I had this idea of cutting the cloudy parts from the stereo-images and inserting the SRTM (in ArcGIS). With this I probably could generate a DEM. But I'm not sure how much sense this makes because I would loose the stereo-view where I insert the SRTM (as I would have to insert the exactly same SRTM-DTM in both ASTER-images).

Do you think it makes sense to insert SRTM-data where there are clouds in ASTER?

Alternatively I could use a different ASTER-scene to insert where I have those voids in my original ASTER-set. But then probably there is the question of the viewing angle of the sensor, if it was not exactly the same, this idea is also useless..?!

Answer (score 1):

You could also generate the DEM with holes in it, and interpolate in the holes. You could even use the SRTM data in this interpolation. One interpolation method that supports this is kriging, which is available in ArcGIS in the spatial analyst and the geostatistical analyst.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate the DEM from your images, and after that, using a cloud mask you could add SRTM values. But you must take into account the vertical differences given by the use of different vertical ellipsoids.